# LaunchScreen.xib single image for all devices?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using the current Xcode and targeting iOS 8.

I'm wondering if it's okay if in my LaunchScreen.xib I put a single imageView that is constrained to all sides of the parent container. Within that image view will be my splash image called: splash.png;

Now here's the kicker, this splash.png will be hi-res and all devices (iPhone/iPad) will use this one image. Is this ok according to apple's guidelines? (note: it's okay with me) I don't mind if it stretches to fit). Also note my app's only in portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's fine, that's because they introduced this new feature (`launchscreen.xib`).

> For deployment targets prior to iOS 8, you add a set of launch images to an asset
>   catalog for each of the possible screen sizes.
>
> New projects are created with a launch screen file called
>   LaunchScreen.xib. Alternately, you can create a new launch screen file
>   using File > New, selecting the User Interface category, and choosing
>   a file type of Launch Screen. The launch screen uses size classes to
>   adapt to different screen sizes and orientations, see [Adapt to Multiple iOS Screen Sizes and Orientations with Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/chapters/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW7) for more
>   information.

Reference : [Create and Set the iOS Launch Images or Launch Screen File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/chapters/AddIcons,Images,andEffects.html)